# image doesn't show when I build the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In Xcode, I am just trying to get an image to show up in my app. I tried taking an image I had previously used in the app and put that into a uiimageview and still, when I build, nothing shows up. I have tried deleting the image file from the app and putting it back in there, I have tried to clean the app and then build. Nothing I am doing works. I just want to be able to put an image in the view and have it show up!

[image: Here is my bundle resources and it shows that the images are all there]

Comment: It will be easier if you provide some code to get the help you seek.

Comment: sorry if I am not explaining this well.  there is no code... all I am trying to do is simply put an image in the app as a uiimageview and get it to display when i build it like i have every other time.

Comment: So you're just setting the image/ background image name of a `UIImageView` from the nib?

Answer (score 0):

Most propably you're just have a typo in the name of the image - in `imageNamed:` - it happens sometimes) And it's case-sensitive - so double check the name.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the image is not added as a bundle resource. To do this, you should go to your `target` settings, and then to `Build Phases` and later check if this image appears in the `Copy bundle resources` section. If not, add it by pressing the **+** button at the end of the list.

I don't know why but in the latest Xcode if you add an image, delete it and then add a new one with the same name, this is not added to the `Bundle resources`.

Comment: all of my images are in the bundle resources.  they just aren't showing up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your images are added to the target which you are trying to build.

Sometimes, it happens when you have two targets lets say one for DEVELOPMENT and one for TESTING and images are added only at one target.

Please re-check if that is the case.